# Precision for double variables

Tags: c#, double

I'm trying to convert a unit to another. But when I enter a value the code assigns the values as double but still outputs integers. I want a 5 digit precision such as a number 12.53527 as output. What is wrong with the following code?:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Program1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Write("Fahrenheit = ");//
            string x_str = Console.ReadLine();


            double celsius = (Convert.ToDouble(x_str) - 32) * (9 / 5);
            Console.Write("Celcius = " + celsius + "\n");

            Console.Write("Enter to terminate");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

edit: guys I will repeat the problem please take a calculator and divide 100 to 68 that is to say 100/68. the calculator shows 1.4705882352941176470588235294118 as a result. in your suggestions I get either 1.40000 or 1.4. I want o have 5 digit precision such as: 1.47058. is it possible in c sharp??

Comment: why people bad vote this question. apparently no one could answer it., strange. then i think it is a good question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`9 / 5` is an integer expression, and the result 1 is. You can convert 1 to a double, but 1 as a double is still 1.

You need to change the expression to floating point using either:

```
9.0 / 5.0
```

Or

```
(double)9 / (double)5
```

Comment: it doesn't work any suggestion here. i want an output of a calculator. your suggestion outputs as a.b0000 this is not 5 digits precision.

Comment: What on Earth are you talking about? My *suggestion* doesn't output *anything*. My code is the correct way to accurately divide two integers and get a result with more precision than integers. If you output `a.b0000`, then maybe you should indicate what code you used to output that, and then show what output you are expecting. Your question has three downvotes because it's not very clear.

Comment: @user16307: You seem a little confused between the difference of how data is stored and how data is displayed. You talk about them like they are the same thing. In LINQPad, `(double)10 / (double)68)` outputs *0.147058823529412*, while `String.Format("{0:#,0.#####}", (double)10 / (double)68)` outputs *0.14706*. I just have no idea what *a.b0000* is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 2):

`9 / 5` gets treated as if the values are both integers. That means the result is `1` (after rounding down `1.8`). You can use `1.8` instead.

Comment: I tried:   double con = 9 / 5;  and then double celsius = (Convert.ToDouble(x_str) - 32) * con; but still it takes as integer. is there a way to divide 9/5 as a double properly in c sharp?

Comment: besides i want to obtain a number with 5 decimals such as 2.34312

Comment: You don't need the variable if you use `1.8`, but it should work with `9.0 / 5.0`

Comment: if I use 1.8 I dont get 5 digit precision I get 1 digit precision. I want an output number such as 12.34547 FIVE DIGITS PRECISION.

Comment: Console.Write("Celcius = " + String.Format("{0:0.00000}", celsius) + "\n");

Comment: it doesnt work any suggestion here. i want an output of a calculator. your suggestion outputs as a.b0000 this is not 5 digits precision.

Comment: pls check the edit of my question. i made it more clear my question.

Answer (score 0):

You've got your conversion multiplier the wrong way up, and you want to make sure it uses Double values rather than integers:

```
double celsius = (Convert.ToDouble(x_str) - 32.0) * (5.0 / 9.0);
```

To force a number to a string with a certain number of decimal places you can use `.ToString()` like this:

```
Console.Write("Celcius = " + celsius.ToString("0.00000") + "\n");
```

More info on format strings: [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

P.S. It is not very realistic to give temperatures to five decimal places.

Comment: it doesnt work it just puts zero after the first decimal in output like 123.50000

Comment: it doesnt work any suggestion here. i want an output of a calculator. your suggestion outputs as a.b0000 this is not 5 digits precision.

Comment: @user16307 There are no more digits to show, so it puts in zeros. If you want it to leave it blank when there are no more digits, use `.ToString("0.#####")`.

Comment: guys i will repeat the problem please take a calculator and divide 100 to 68 that is to say 100/68. the calculator shows 1.4705882352941176470588235294118 as a result. in your suggestions i get either 1.40000 or 1.4. I want o have 5 digit precision such as: 1.47058. is it possible in c sharp??

Comment: @user16307 Once you have corrected your conversion factor, enter 34.647044 as the Fahrenheit value and you will get 1.47058.